# jQuery: Get parent height and assign to a selector inside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a way to change a selector's height to its parent's height via jQuery but haven't found any solution yet, you can clearly see in this page I need to get the height of each `#accordion ul li` and set it to the `.status-green`

http://jsbin.com/udajen/8/edit

Thank you!

Comment: Try this fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/tariqulazam/nZKhm/3/

I just modified it to be wrapped within the document.ready function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the work example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mikhailov/yQfFc/

```
$("#accordion li").each(function(index, value) {
    var $value = $(this);
    var current = $value.height() - 2;
    $value.find(".status-green").height(current);
});
```

the second option is to iterate through .sentence divs:

```
$("#accordion .sentence").each(function(index, value) {
    var $value = $(this);
    var current = $value.height() + 10;
    $value.siblings(".status-green").height(current);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realized what was my main problem after comparing your example with mine on my page? I was using Display:None for the #accordion on my page, I removed it and set that with jQuery instead of stylesheet so the jQuery doesn't take it as disabled selector and it worked perfectly! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the `.status-green`s height same as associated `.sentence` height, you must calculate their `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` too. here is the complete code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Javad_Amiry/REPuQ/1/

and the js will be:

```
$("#accordion .sentence").each(function () {
    var current = $(this).height();
    var p_top = $(this).css("padding-top");
    var p_bot = $(this).css("padding-bottom");
    $(this).parent().find(".status-green").css({
        height:current,
        "padding-top":p_top,
        "padding-bottom":p_bot
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Javad, but jQuery `.height()` calculates the paddings too.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but not in all browsers! You can test it! This is based on my experience, but you can test it your-self

Comment: you can pay attention to this line in mikhailov's code-snippet: `var current = $value.height() + 10;` that is pointing about `.height()` and `padding` really